# Read the URL from the properties file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

Can we modify an apk after it has been created? because I want to make such an APK that reads the URL through the **property file** but it does not need to rebuild eg. I want to change the port number so I will change it through the property file or Is there another way?

Comment: and where that property file will be? and how you are going to do the changes in them?

Comment: I will unzip the apk and in that, I will change the URL in the property file but apk not being installed after changes. so is there any other way to do it, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using

possibly duplicate: https://cutt.ly/Vv8FQ0u

```
ant.propertyfile(
        file: "myfile.properties") {
        entry( key: "propertyName", value: "propertyValue")
        entry( key: "anotherProperty", operation: "del")
    }
```